# Access Value from JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having issues accessing values from json using json.parse. This is my JSON:

```
  [  
   {  
      "store":[  
         {  
            "name":"Grand Theft Auto V"
         },
         {  
            "skuid":"UP1004-CUSA00419_00-GTAVDIGITALDOWNL-U001"
         },
         {  
            "releasedate":"2014-11-18T00:00:00Z"
         }         //...
```

I'm trying to get the `name` from the `store` array.

```
var cif = JSON.parse(response);

// Tried the following:
alert(cif["store"][0].name);
alert(cif.store[0].name);
alert(cif[0].store.name);
alert(cif["store"].name);

if(cif.store[0].name) $("#cif-title").html(cif.store[0].name);
```

How do I access this value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work.

```
alert(cif[0]["store"][0]["name"]);
```

or

```
alert(cif[0].store[0].name);
```

Comment: That indeed works, but other values like `skuid` return undefined with this method, is there a fix for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try `console.log(cif[0].store[0].name)`